# Do I need an enterprise license to work on Dynamics CRM 365 with Visual Studio Professional 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365

Having started with a new company, they are looking at what will be the right licence that they can get me for developing CRM with.

I am looking at Visual Studio Professional, can anyone confirm whether or not I will run into any issues with Professional and whether there is any need for an enterprise licence?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, as much as readers want to help here, it's a legal question and not a programming one.

Comment: Please could you explain then where I am supposed to ask these questions @halfer? I am a beginner in the stack overflow forums, so any direction would be helpful...

Comment: Hi James.  I am not aware that Stack Overflow has a Q&A site for asking software licensing questions. They have a forum for quite a lot of things (see the footer) but I am not sure about that one, sorry. Perhaps there is a Dynamics CRM sub on Reddit? The on-topic rules of Reddit subs tend to be looser than ours, so maybe that would be OK. Have a read [of this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to see what sort of questions work well here.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know halfer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Professional is more than enough.

Even Community edition technically will work just fine.

Comment: Thanks Sergey, if only I could use community! Unfortunately though, they are an enterprise company, so I couldn't use community to develop for it.

Comment: AFAIK As long as it's less than (5?) developers, the community edition is okay no matter the size of the company